# Error deploying WAR file in the Tomcat server- org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener not loading

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, war

My project is working fine in my local machine running through eclipse and tomcat server 7. Same project I am generating WAR file by doing `Maven install` and deploying it in tomcat server. After deployment project is not running and giving **404 Not Found**.

In the log file I am getting error like this :

```
       SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'preAuthendicationFilter' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'preAuthendicationFilter' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'authenticationManager' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userDetailsService' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.acinfotech.crowdtxt.jpa.service.PersistenceService com.acinfotech.crowdtxt.secure.UserDetailsServiceImpl.persistenceService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'persistenceService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.acinfotech.crowdtxt.jpa.util.PropertyUtil com.acinfotech.crowdtxt.jpa.service.PersistenceServiceImpl.propertyUtil; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'propertyUtil' defined in URL [jar:file:/Users/mindpro/Documents/apache-tomcat-7.0.59/webapps/crowdtxt/WEB-INF/lib/crowdtxt-persistence-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/acinfotech/crowdtxt/jpa/util/PropertyUtil.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:154)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1158)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:610)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5524)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1081)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1877)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)   
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.acinfotech.crowdtxt.jpa.util.PropertyUtil.getPropertiesFromEnvironmentVariable(PropertyUtil.java:86)
    at com.acinfotech.crowdtxt.jpa.util.PropertyUtil.<clinit>(PropertyUtil.java:23)
    ... 119 more
```

**Application-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.acinfotech.crowdtxt.jpa.dao"/>

     <!--Bean to load properties file -->
    <!-- <bean id="placeholderConfig" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"> 
        <property name="location" value="file:${CROWDTEXT_PROPERTY_FILE}"/>
    </bean> --> 

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/crowdtxt"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
        <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
        <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>
   </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
        <!-- spring based scanning for entity classes-->
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.acinfotech.crowdtxt.jpa.model"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"/>

</beans>
```

Can someone please help me out what would be the problem? I am unable to find it out where I am doing wrong. I have all dependencies set in `pom.xml`

Comment: insufficient information. post more of the logs

Comment: spring is not able to instantiate PropertyUtil . Can u post the exception cause. Last exception in the stack trace. From error logs :      org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'propertyUtil' defined in URL [jar:file:/Users/mindpro/Documents/apache-tomcat-7.0.59/webapps/crowdtxt/WEB-INF/lib/crowdtxt-persistence-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/acinfotech/crowdtxt/jpa/util/PropertyUtil.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just noticed that this project is working fine in eclipse but not in standalone server. Copy all runtime properties you set in eclipse tomcat config and paste it in standalone tomcat catalaina file. You can find for java opts and add it thr.

There is a null pointer exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.acinfotech.crowdtxt.jpa.util.PropertyUtil.getPropertiesFromEnvironmentVariable(PropertyUtil.java:86)
at com.acinfotech.crowdtxt.jpa.util.PropertyUtil.<clinit>(PropertyUtil.java:23)
... 119 more
```

You can put a debug point at line 86 in PropertyUtil class. From the method name getPropertiesFromEnvironmentVariable, I guess some environment variable is not set, or there is some problem in getting its value.

If you cannot debug, then try to use System.out.println statements to see what is null.

I hope you can debug from here.